How to obtain the pdf of $V,W$ when $V=g(X,Y), W=h(X,Y)$ (2 functions of two random variables)
If two functions $V=X+Y$ and $W=X-Y$ are given, where X, Y are random variables, how do we calculate $f_{V,W}(v,w)$. Assume $v,w>0$. (Problem taken from "Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes for Engineers" by Henry Starks & John W. Woods- 4th edition).
This will provide an idea of which area we seek to find.

I can understand that the cdf should be
$$
F_{V,W}(v,w)=\int_{-\infty}^{(v+w)/2} \int_{x-w}^{v-x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx \; \; (1)
$$
The book then proceeds to determine the pdf in the following manner: below image.
My question pertains to one of the steps in the below image. Particularly, from where does the term in I've circled in red arise?


The red term arises because of the Leibniz rule. You differentiate an integral w.r.t. $w.$ The upper integration limit and the integrand both depend on $w.$

@KurtG. Ah yes I see. However, is the upper limit (v-x) dependent on w?

This does not sound like you see. The integral you differentiate is the outer, aka $dx-,$ integral in (1). What us its upper limit?

You're right I didn't see before. I should use x=upper limit for the dx. I was able to get the red term. Thank you!
